# Can not unmarhsal xml over maven

Tags: java, xml, maven

I have junit test which is unmarshal my xml to object **just fine it works!**

But when I run maven command `mvn surefire-report:report -Pmytests` it can not unmarhsal xml to object. 
WITH NO EXCEPTION I HAVE NULL OBJECT

My pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.project</groupId>
    <artifactId>automation</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>


    <build>
        <directory>target</directory>
        <sourceDirectory>src/main/java</sourceDirectory>
        <outputDirectory>target/classes</outputDirectory>
        <finalName>AUTOMATION-01</finalName>
        <testSourceDirectory>src/test/java/com/tests</testSourceDirectory>
        <testOutputDirectory>target/test-classes</testOutputDirectory>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            </resource>
        </resources>


        <plugins>

            <plugin>
                <inherited>true</inherited>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>attach-sources</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>jar</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <inherited>true</inherited>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <updateReleaseInfo>true</updateReleaseInfo>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <filesets>
                        <fileset>
                            <directory>target</directory>
                        </fileset>
                    </filesets>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>


    <profiles>

        <profile>
            <id>myTests</id>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>2.15</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                            <argLine>-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8</argLine>
                            <groups>com.testgroups.myTestGroup</groups>
                            <redirectTestOutputToFile>true</redirectTestOutputToFile>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>

        </profiles>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.ws</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxws-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.11</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.11</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jaxb</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-runtime</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.11</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.12</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
            <version>11.2.0.3</version>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <systemPath>${project.basedir}/lib/ojdbc6.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.perf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>perf4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <systemPath>${project.basedir}/lib/perf4j-0.9.16.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.gelfj</groupId>
            <artifactId>gelfj</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.1</version>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <systemPath>${project.basedir}/lib/gelfj-1.0.1.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>4.5.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

Could you please help me to solve this problem?

Comment: You have opened a `<profiles>` tag but there is no corresponding `</profiles>` tag. Is this a copy paste error in the question?

Comment: Yes it just my copy paste error. But problem is different

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maven differentiates between resources, and test resources. Maybe you are putting the xml file, which is being marshalled, somewhere underneath the `src/main/resources` folder?

If thats the case, try copying the xml file to `src/test/resources`